# How to install Android Studio on ubuntu 32 bit, error No server to serve request

Tags: android-studio, installation, ubuntu-16.04, 32-bit

I am having trouble to fix the gradle error: `No server to serve request`. With a lot of googling I tried to check with `ldd appt2`, but ldd did not even work. Then, with `file appt2` I found that it was a 64-bit executable, and because I run with a 32-bit ubuntu, this might explain why ldd did not work, and this might be a real problem. But I do not find anything on installing Android Studio for 32 bit.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google dropped support for 32 bit Linux, although it still supports 32 bit Windows.**

Also Note
Android SDK stopped supporting dev on 32 bit Linux OS since > 23 upwards

As a workaround,
You can install run 32 bit Windows on a Virtual Machine! and develop app on it.

Also checkout the [Android Studio Archive](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html) to Download Android Studio